# Exclude subdirectories

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

How can I exclude every subdirectory using grep or any other method?

By this commands:

```
awk -F '&' '{ print $1 }' file | grep $myPath | sort | uniq
```

There is an output:

```
home/docs/file1
home/docs/file2
home/docs/subdir/file3
home/docs/file4
home/docs/anydir/file5
```

But the output I need:

```
home/docs/file1
home/docs/file2
home/docs/file4
```

This is just an example, i don't know how many columns there will be.

Comment: What command are you running to generate that list?

Comment: What's producing the original output?

Comment: awk -F '&' '{ print $1 }' log | grep "home/docs" | sort | uniq

Comment: So the contents of `file` are a list of paths, and you want to match only the paths that have three components (e.g. `home/docs/file1`), is that right? Is `$myPath` set to `home/docs`? The more specifics you share the more specific help you'll get. It's difficult to guess what you're doing or trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `myPath=home/docs` you just need to match for paths that don't have any subsequent `/` characters, e.g.:

```
grep "^${myPath}/[^/]*$"
```

- `^` match the beginning of the line (ensuring we don't match some deeper subdirectory that also matches `myPath`, such as `/home/docs/foo/home/docs/bar`)
- `${myPath}` using `{}` helps delimit variables in larger strings
- `/` match exactly one literal slash following `myPath`
- `[^/]*` match any number of characters that aren't `/`
- `$` match the end of the line (ensuring that we match the full line, not just part of it)

Example:

```
$ myPath=home/docs
$ cat <<EOF | grep "^${myPath}/[^/]*$"
> home/docs/file1
> home/docs/file2
> home/docs/subdir/file3
> home/docs/file4
> home/docs/anydir/file5
> EOF

home/docs/file1
home/docs/file2
home/docs/file4
```